# Arm Assembly Instructions: POP what means as return of a function

Tags: assembly, arm

What does it means

```
LDR.W           R8, [SP+0x10+var_10],#4
POP{R4-R7, PC}
```

if I found that instruction at the end of a function?

Thanks 
Paolo

Comment: does this help? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#ARM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read a bit about "[stack](http://thinkingeek.com/2013/02/07/arm-assembler-raspberry-pi-chapter-10/)", I assume.

Think in the stack as a region in memory that works as a LIFO: last register to be "pushed", has to be the first to be "popped". This way, it is easy to keep track of variables that are saved to comply with [AAPCS](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf).

So, sort answer is: that instruction restores values to r4-r7, and sets PC to the LR, that is, the point of the program immediately after this function.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Arm website:
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Babefbce.html

POP  {R0,R6,PC} ; Pop r0,r6 and PC from the stack, then branch to the new PC.